# AngularJS directive templateUrl not loading into view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am using ui-view to route me to a partial.

```
//route.provider.js

(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .provider('RouteService', RouteService);

RouteService.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function RouteService ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    var service = {};

    this.$get = function() { return service; };

    this.initialize = function() {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'viewModel'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'viewModel'
            })

            //TODO Impliment the following partial pages...

            .state('gensim', {
                url: '/gensim',
                templateUrl: 'general-simulation/simulation.view.html',
                controller: 'TabsController',
                controllerAs: 'tabs'
            })
            <...more routes...>
    }
}
})();
```

The issue I am having is once it routes to

```
// general-simulation/simulation.view.html
```

I'd like it to use a custom directive to insert more html into the page.
Inside simulation.view.html I have this.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>General Simulation</h1>
            <gs-tabs><h1>TEST!!!!</h1></gs-tabs>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is constructed in

```
// tabs.directives.js
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('gsTabs', gsTabs);

function gsTabs () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateURL: 'tabs.view.html'
    };
}

})();
```

Finally, my tabs.view.html looks like this.

```
<h1>YOU HAVE ENTERED TABS PARTIAL</h1>
```

When I navigate to the page that displays simulation.view all I can see is:

**General Simulation**

**TEST!!!!**

So what am I doing wrong here. I checked for camelCasing and the page is not showing in errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I viewed the network calls in chrome's dev tools.
simulation.view.html is being loaded but tabs.view.html isn't.

Request URL:http://sdc-stagt01/AngularJS/general-simulation/simulation.view.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.19.8.96:80

The file substructure is:

> /general-simulation/tabs/tabs.controller.js
>   /general-simulation/tabs/tabs.directives.js
>   /general-simulation/tabs/tabs.view.html 
>   /general-simulation/simulation.view.html

Comment: inspect xhr requests made in browser dev tools to see if request made correctly and it's status and response body. Seems strange all the other templates are in directories but `tabs` isn't

Comment: try to use `ng-include` instead of your 'gsTabs' directive and as @charlietfl said, check your path to the template

Comment: change `templateURL` to `templateUrl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

putting comment as answer

change `templateURL` to `templateUrl`

Comment: I'm a freaking moron sometimes. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

So [entre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139099/entre)'s comment was a big help. That got chrome dev to start spitting out errors.

[charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) Was on the right track with mentioning my file structure as well. I needed to change my directive to look like this:

```
templateUrl: 'general-simulation/tabs/tabs.view.html'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me since before I was trying to access my view with: `templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'` , but it worked when I added the parent folder: `templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html'`. I was using the Angular routing tutorial in the documentation. Do you know why it won't work with a simple reference with './name.of.file.html'?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here. `templateUrl` not `templateURL`

```
function gsTabs () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateURL: 'tabs.view.html' // change this to templateUrl
    };
}
```